# Is openAI text generation models an extension of embedding models?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, embeddings, gpt, stanford-nlp

we can creating embeddings using below code

```
import openai
response = openai.Embedding.create(
  input="porcine pals say",
  model="text-embedding-ada-002"
)
```

And we can generate text using below code

```
def get_completion(prompt, model="text-davinci-003"):
messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
model=model,
messages=messages,
temperature=0,
)
return response.choices[0].message["content"]
```

are text completions models extension of embeddings generation models, I mean is it like the embeddings generation models are further finetuned for chat/text generation?

or is it like both models are completely different in terms of their training and architecture?

Comment: Yo did you find the answer to this? I'm curious as well.